# Split Flux into lists containing up to 20 elements in Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I want to split `Flux` into multiple `List`s (or sub-`Flux`es) in a way that each one will contain up to 20 elements.

My Flux:

```
"a","s","x"...
```

converted to:
`List<String>, List<String>`
or
`Flux<String>, Flux<String>` - each one with up to 20 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that `Flux.window(20)` returning `Flux<Flux<T>>` is what you are looking for. Check its [reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#window-int-) on which one can read:

> Split this Flux sequence into multiple Flux windows containing maxSize
> elements (or less for the final window) and starting from the first
> item. Each Flux window will onComplete after maxSize items have been
> routed.

---

*(Thanks @MichaelBerry for the hint)*

There is also `Flux.buffer(20)` which will return `Flux<List<T>>`. In the [reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#buffer-int-) we can read:

> Collect incoming values into multiple List buffers that will be
> emitted by the returned Flux each time the given max size is reached
> or once this Flux completes.

Comment: `buffer()` would also be of relevance here, as it'll directly convert to a `Flux<List<String>>` if that's a preferred case for the OP.

Comment: That is in fact true. Many thanks @MichaelBerry for the hint. I will add it to my answer ;)